# Should PR AUC be used in cases where there is less than 5 positives vs 10000+ negatives?

Tags: machine-learning, roc, regression-strategies, auc

I understand that the PR-AUC provides a better accuracy estimate than the ROC-AUC in the case of highly skewed datasets. But if I have a test dataset with less than 5 positives and 10000+ negatives, can I still use it? Is there a better alternative in such cases?

Buy the way, I have calculated the ROC-AUC based on the test dataset above and I got AUC>0.75. I think this is probably an overly optimistic assessment of the classififers's performance and, hence, I am looking for a better peformance measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your effective sample size is 5 so you do not have an adequate sample for doing *anything*, not even predicting the overall average outcome in the absence of any predictors.  So the choices you make about measuring accuracy are "too late".  Note that when $Y$ is binary it is not a good idea to consider classification.  Better almost always is to predict the probability that $Y=1$.  Classification is an arbitrary manipulation that has to be completely re-thought when you move to a sample that has a prevalence of $Y=1$ that is much different than $\frac{5}{10000}$.